# Using custom attribute than source for sortable list

Tags: sorting, admin-on-rest

First, thanks for this great library :)

Currently, AOR use the "source" attribute for sorting the list.
Is there a way to use a custom attribute ?

My backend api expect "object type" pour sorting list, something like the following :

- posts?sort=post.createdAt&order=desc
- posts?sort=user.username
- posts?sort=user.id

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

That's the job of your rest client to translate the aor parameters into what your api expect. See the doc about how to write a custom one: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client